# IE Browser Support issue

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

[This is my website](http://www.privatelabeledbusinesscredit.com/)

I have cross-browser issue with IE. In that video play button contains border-radius that is not supported in IE. I have used video.js file.

CSS I used to solve this issue:

```
-web kit-border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
```

I have try this CSS code but not solve this issue:

```
-ms-border-radius: 25px;
```

Comment: IE has supported `border-radius` since IE9.

Comment: please specify the version of IE that you are testing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here try this

Internet Explorer:

```
#yourId , * html #yourId , *+html #yourId {
-web kit-border-radius: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;            
border-radius: 25px\9;
            border-radius: 25px\0/;    
}
```

did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding [PIE.htc](http://css3pie.com/) to your website.  Especially if you're targeting IE < 9.

Comment: I have try this issue but not solve..